# Change 2 or more query string parameters into folder structure

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to change

`http://example.com/view?i=52&t=rocket`

to

`http://example.com/view/52/rocket`

I currently have (for `?i=` only):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /view\?i=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ /view/%1? [L,R]

RewriteRule ^view/([0-9]+)$ /view?i=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Also, how would I rewrite it for the following too (without `/view`)?

`http://example.com/?i=52&t=rocket`

```
                  ^ possibly without the /
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+view\?i=([0-9]+)&t=([^&\s]+)
RewriteRule ^ /view/%1/%2? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+\?i=([0-9]+)&t=([^&\s]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+view\?i=([0-9]+)\s
RewriteRule ^ /view/%1? [L,R]

RewriteRule ^view/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /view?i=$1&t=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ ?i=$1&t=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^view/([0-9]+)$ /view?i=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search using this regex:

```
[^\/]+=
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/vX8wL3/1)

And replace the matched text by empty string.

---

Explaining:

```
[^\/]     # looks for not '/' characters
+         # at least one of them together
=         # and must end in an '=' character
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First one:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*/view)\?i=(\d*)&t=(.*) $1/$2/$3
```

Second one:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/view\?i=(\d*)&t=(.*) $1/$2/$3
```